# properly sanitize multiple user inputs with mysqli

Tags: php, security, mysqli, bind

Im currently using mysqli, and I want a way to properly sanitize every single user input. Im looking for the most simple lightweight way to do this, as I understand that Im NOT supposed to use mysql_real_escape....

my query is like so

```
$stmt = $sql->prepare("INSERT INTO Persons (msg, ip, time, main, twit, city, lat, lon, lang)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
```

as i understand i'm supposed to use the function bindParam... If i use it like so, am i completley securing my user inputs?

```
$stmt->bind_param('sssssssss', $_POST[msg], ('$ip'), ('$date'), '$_POST[main]', '$_POST[twit]',  ('$cit'), ('$lat'), ('$lon'), '$_POST[lang]');
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

If this isn't securing my user inputs how do i properly do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to prepare the statement to be safe.  Something like below (its probably not 100% but gives you an idea)

```
 $sql = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");


    $stmt = $sql->prepare("INSERT INTO Persons (msg, ip, time, main, twit, city, lat, lon, lang)
        VALUES
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("sssssssss",$_POST[msg], $ip, $date, $_POST[main], $_POST[twit],  $cit, $lat, $lon, $_POST[lang]);
    $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: hey sorry what's the "Ssssssss" for?

Comment: Its to define the inputs as strings. each S stands for each input. if it was I it'd be integer or d for decimal.  Look into mysql->prepare on the php docs it explains it all better than i can.

Comment: Im getting the following error!
 error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

Comment: cos its $sql->bind_param() not bindParam in mysqli. I get mixed up between mysqli, pdo and my custom DB classes.  Read this it has examples on how to properly prepare mysqli queries http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: Still an error. Take a look at my edit: that's the code that is currently giving me an error!

Comment: remove the () and remove the ' too so it reads like this `$stmt->bind_param('sssssssss', $_POST[msg],$ip,$date,$_POST[main], $_POST[twit],$cit,$lat,$lon,$_POST[lang];`  I assuming your doing the DB connection etc correctly

Comment: You've not created your mysqli Object properly then (or done it in a procedural way) Can you give us your full code for all the sql stuff including the DB connection/class creation etc It should be something like above (I'll update my post)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to follow basic **PHP syntax**

`'$_POST[msg]'` would be inserted as a literal `$_POST[msg]` string, while you expecting a *value* for $_POST['msg'] variable.